# How to generate a unique random id for post in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.2

I want to produce unique post identifier for posts in my blogging application.

Currently I am using `SecureRandom.hex(10)` for generating unique post identifier for my blogging site but I am not sure is it safe SecureRandom for this purpose.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Ruby doc:

> This library is an interface for secure random number generator which is suitable for generating session key in HTTP cookies, etc.

I had similar problem, I used Digest library.

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(post.title + post.created_at.to_s) #=> "b4809d..."
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for this function because I could not find it. Is it a problem if I use SecureRandom hash?

Comment: You can open this [page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) or run `ri Digest`. I think it is fine to use `SecureRandom`.

Comment: I get "Could not find gem 'Digest' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile." when I add 'Digest' or 'digest' to the gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: Also, if I try `gem install digest` it returns "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'digest' (>= 0) in any repository"

Answer (score 3):

If anyone looking for just unique numeric token. I'd rather use Time based approach. For not much-frequent requests (max one per second). You can use

```
Time.now.to_i
```

To get it in string `Time.now.to_i.to_s`
If you are dealing with frequent requests (thousands per second) while generating token. Use float conversation

```
Time.now.to_f #1532415770.0032046
```

To get it in string you can use `Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub(".", "")` although not recommended.

The chance of repentance of above value is close to null in current universe.

Comment: This seems like a good approach, @Aarvy. However I'm curious why the floating option has a better performance from the integer one? I'd expect both to be O(1)